# How to preserve stdout and stderr order read from forked process?

Tags: c, select, fork

I have a parent process which forked a child process. I create pipes for the stdin/out/err of the child process pass the store the fds of the other end in the parent as `pipe[0]`, `pipe[1]`, `pipe[2]`.

I'm seeing a race condition where `select()` will return due to data ready on `pipe[2]`, but then data becomes ready on `pipe[1]` and `pipe[1]`'s data gets written first because the `if` statement for `pipe[1]`.

Is there a way for me to avoid this race condition and preserve the order with respect to when the child process wrote to them?

Here's the relevant code:

```
// pipe[0] = in of child
// pipe[1] = out of child
// pipe[2] = err of child

char buf[2048];

fd_set rfds;
while (keepRunning) {
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(pipe[1], &rfds);
    FD_SET(pipe[2], &rfds);

    int rc = select(pipe[2]+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (rc) {
        if (FD_ISSET(pipe[1], &rfds)) {
            write(1, buf, read(pipe[1], buf, sizeof(buf)));
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(pipe[2], &rfds)) {
            write(2, buf, read(pipe[2], buf, sizeof(buf)));
        }
    } else if (rc == -1) {
        perror("select()");
    }
}
```

Comment: separate selects for each file descriptor

Comment: That would give much more bias to the descriptor that select was called on first. Would it not?

Comment: probably in microseconds

Comment: Well, calling select once will block until data is ready or it times out (i don't have timeout set). It is not recommended to use timeout. But even with a timeout, calling two selects would introduce as much bias as your timeout duration.

Comment: Otherwise 2 threads might be another thought

Comment: Two threads would probably work. I guess what I'm looking for is something like Python's `select.select()` which returns tuples containing which file descriptors caused `select()` to return. Although it is very possible that internally Python can't keep sequential out and err from getting out of order.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26272/discussion-between-kevindtimm-and-patrick)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of that too, almost answered with that -- until I remembered it wasn't in your language of choice :)